# Почему данный код не работает

Tags: java, события, minecraft, mod, forge

```
package com.gc.superslots;

import net.minecraft.world.entity.player.Inventory;
import net.minecraft.world.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.event.TickEvent.PlayerTickEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;

@Mod(deleteslot.MODID)
public class deleteslot
{
    public static final String MODID = "superslots";

    public deleteslot()
    {
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(deleteslot.this); //Подписываем местные методы на события
    }
    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void onTick(PlayerTickEvent event) {
        Inventory inv = new Inventory(event.player); // Получаем инвентарь
        ItemStack slot = inv.getItem(9); //Получаем хранящееся в слоте

        if (!slot.isEmpty()) { // Проверяем не пустой ли слот
            inv.setItem(9, ItemStack.EMPTY); // Очищаем слот
            System.out.println(slot.getCount()); //Выводим кол-во удалённых предметов
        }

    }
}
```

Ожидаемый результат: постоянно очищаеться слот сверху справа и пишеться сколько предметов удалено

Получаемый результат: никакого

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых `PlayerTickEvent` относится ко всем игрокам которые неподалёку, а не только к игроку. Если ты хочешь получать только Tick своего игрока, сверяй его по

```java
if (event.player != FMLClientHandler.instance().getClientPlayerEntity()) return; // THIS player only
// Если чит сетевой то ещё
if (!event.player.world.isRemote) return; // network only
```

Во вторых получение инвентаря, идёт от игрока.

```java
for (ItemStack stack: player.inventory.mainInventory)
```

В третьих `PlayerTickEvent` происходит около 20 раз в секнду, повесишь кучу лагов на клиент. Уж лучше мониторить пакеты изменения инвентаря!

И на закуску, ты не можешь просто взять и удалить предмет. Если ты хочешь удалить предмет по сети, то это надо делать через

```java
player.connection.sendPacket
```

Которые идут от интерфейса `Packet`

**А теперь самое интересное, от версии к версии Майнкрафт и ForgeAPI очень сильно менялся. Наверняка без версий тебе некто не скажет!**

Answer (score 1):

Там игроку создаёться новый инвентарь вместо взаимодействия со старым, надо было написать вместо new Inventory(event.player) написать event.player.getInventory()